# Como criar validações específicas usando Regex

Tags: php, regex

Tenho os seguintes dados

> 30140083|MG 13407061|07309482697|12/01/86|EMILLY L V GOMES|4984012024889591|10/2018|557
> 3283005|165055881|07309480805|11/18/16|AILTON B TEGON|5549320054855241|6/2018|177
> 3691100|17714445|07309395883|01/07/67|MARGARETE P SAN|319150122924465|12/2023|8671

Gostaria de criar validações e/ou condições utilizando as `Expressões Regulares` para verificar se os cartões iniciados com (4, 5, 6) tem como seu código de segurança a quantidade de 3 (três) caracteres. Já os cartões iniciados com (3) tem como seu código de segurança a quantidade de 4 (quatro) caracteres. Os respectivos valores tais como:

- **4** = Visa (*CVV: 3*)
- **5** = Mastercard (*CVV: 3*)
- **6** = Elo/Discover/Diners Club (*CVV: 3*)
- **3** = American Express (*CVV: 4*)

Para obter os valores, sem definir as condições utilizo este pattern: `(\d{15,16})[^<](\d{1,2})[^<](\d{2,4})[^<](\d{3})` mas só consigo obter valores como estes: *"4984012024889591|10/2018|557", "5549320054855241|6/2018|177"* já este: *"319150122924465|12/2023|8671"* termina ficando de fora do padrão. Utilizo a função [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) do PHP. Preciso obter todos os respectivos valores para validá-los com o [Algorítmo Luhn](https://github.com/maxipago/sdk-card-validation) e retornar para o front-end.

Vale ressaltar alguns poréns..

**BANDEIRA**            | **BIN (iniciais)**

---

- American Express          | 34, 37
- Aura          | 50
- Diners Club           | 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 36, 38, 39
- Discover      | 6011, 622, 64, 65
- Elo               | 401178, 401179, 431274, 438935, 451416, 4573, 4576, 506, 509, 636, 6500, 6504, 6505, 6507, 6509, 6516, 6550, 504175, 627780
- Hipercard | 606282
- JCB | 3088, 3096, 3112, 3158, 3337, 35
- Mastercard | 5, 2
- Visa | 4

Nem todos possuem como seu identificador apenas o 1° dígito, assim como o *American Express*, *Diners Club* e o *JCB* seus primeiros dígitos é **3**, ai fica a questão que não consegui solucionar usando apenas `RegExp`.

### EDIT

Já tentei acrescentar `{3, 4}` pra obter tanto *CVV* com 3 dígitos, quanto 4 dígitos, mas pode ocorrer de que ao lado do *CVV* conter uma data, exemplo: *"5549320054855241|6/2018|17701/01/2021"*, consequentemente o `RegExp` irá obter o maior valor, o contrário de *"5549320054855241|6/2018|177|01/01/2021"* iria me retornar tranquilo somente *"5549320054855241|6/2018|177"*, por isso a necessidade de aplicar uma condição, a partir da Bandeira do Cartão, pois se inicialmente ele começar com **4** ou **5** sei que seus respectivos *CVV* tem somente 3 dígitos. Já em casos como o `American Express` que possui 4 dígitos de *CVV* e 15 dígitos de Cartão, conseguiria distinguir e obter os valores de forma correta.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Se a ideia é somente pegar os números,  não seria somente acrescentar `{3,4}` no final do regex? `/(\d{15,16})[^<](\d{1,2})[^<](\d{2,4})[^<](\d{3,4})/`.

Comment: @WeslleyAraújo não, não,  a propósito já tentei deste jeito, porém a forma como eu recebo os dados podem se diferenciar, por exemplo, assim como *"MG 13407061|0730948269"* o 13407061 está ao lado deste delimitador **|** (que por sinal pode ser diferente), ao lado do CVV podem ter outros números, tais como data e etc.. Tipo assim: *"4984012024889591|10/2018|55701/01/2021"* ai se no pattern, ele contesse {3,4} ou seja ele irá tentar pegar o maior número, porém seguindo o padrão, a bandeira Visa, iniciada com número 4 tem somente 3 dígitos do seu código de segurança (cvv)

Comment: consequentemente ele iria obter *"4984012024889591|10/2018|5570"* que por sinal está inválido.

Comment: Este exemplo com data depois do CVV não está na pergunta. Sugiro [edit] e colocar todas as variações possíveis, senão qualquer resposta será incompleta... Aliás, vc só quer validar ou quer  pegar cada informação isoladamente (o número do cartão, o CVV, etc)?

Comment: Editei, e conforme ir tentando irei adicionando.

Comment: @hkotsubo necessariamente preciso obter-los de forma separada, mas que façam parte de um grupo só, nos `for` ou `foreach` preciso pegar cada grupo (cartão, mês, ano, cvv) e adiciona-los á um `Array Object`, pois faço as 4 validações. 1° se o cartão é verdadeiro (se está conforme o algoritmo valida), 2° se o vencimento, ou seja, a data de validade do cartão não está vencida (menor que o mês ou ano atual) e se o cvv corresponde a bandeira (seja Amex, Visa, Master, Hiper, Elo, etc...)

Comment: Espero que estes dados sejam fictícios

Comment: @EduardoBissi apenas para ilustrações, são cartões verdadeiros, porém inválidos.. não pertence a uma pessoa "física" ou "jurídica".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez regex não seja a melhor solução. Em vez disso, você poderia simplesmente separar os dados e tratá-los separadamente. Supondo que cada registro está em uma linha, um "esqueleto" da ideia geral seria:

```
$dados = <<<DADOS
30140083|MG 13407061|07309482697|12/01/86|EMILLY L V GOMES|4984012024889591|10/2018|557
3283005|165055881|07309480805|11/18/16|AILTON B TEGON|5549320054855241|6/2018|177
3691100|17714445|07309395883|01/07/67|MARGARETE P SAN|319150122924465|12/2023|8671
DADOS;
// para cada linha dos dados
foreach (explode("\r\n", $dados) as $line) {
    // separar as informações (supondo que o separador sempre é "|")
    $partes = explode('|', $line);
    // supondo que os dados sempre estão nas mesmas posições
    $numero = $partes[5];
    $cvv = $partes[7];

    // --------- validações ---------
    // exemplo: Diners Club (coloque todos os valores que o cartão pode iniciar)
    $tmp = substr($numero, 0, 3);
    if ($tmp == '300' || $tmp == '301' || etc... ) {
        // cartão é Diners
        $tamanho_cvv = 4;
    } else if ($numero[0] == '4') {
        // cartão é Visa
        $tamanho_cvv = 3;
    } // etc (coloque as outras condições específicas de cada bandeira, ajustando o tamanho do CVV para cada caso)

    // verificar CVV
    if (strlen($cvv) == $tamanho_cvv) {
        // tamanho CVV ok
    } else {
        // CVV com tamanho errado
    }
}
```

Claro que dá para melhorar, isso é só uma ideia inicial, mas uma vez tendo o número do cartão e o CVV, você pode validar da maneira que achar melhor. Poderia ser por exemplo:

```
function getTamanhoCvv($numero_cartao) {
    $digito = intval($numero_cartao[0]);
    if (4 <= $digito && $digito <= 6)
        return 3;

    if ($digito == 3)
        return 4;

    // adicione mais casos se necessário

    // se chegou aqui, dá erro (número inválido?), ou retorna algum valor default, veja o que faz mais sentido no seu caso
}

function diners($numero_cartao) {
    $tmp = intval(substr($numero_cartao, 0, 3));
    if (300 <= $tmp && $tmp <= 305)
        return TRUE;
    $tmp = intval(substr($numero_cartao, 0, 2));
    return $tmp == 36 || $tmp == 38 || $tmp == 39;
}

function getBandeira($numero_cartao) {
    if (diners($numero_cartao)) {
        return 'Diners Club';
    }

    // teste as outras bandeiras de maneira similar...
}

...
$numero = // obter número do cartão conforme já explicado
$cvv = // obter CVV conforme já explicado
$tamanho_cvv = getTamanhoCvv($numero);
$bandeira = getBandeira($numero);

// verificar CVV
if (strlen($cvv) == $tamanho_cvv) {
    // tamanho CVV ok
} else {
    // CVV com tamanho errado
}

etc...
```

E para verificar os casos que tem data depois do CVV, bastaria fazer algo como:

```
// verifica se tem data após o CVV
if (preg_match('#(\d{3,4})\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}#', $cvv, $match)) {
    $cvv = $match[1];
}
```

Como a ideia não é validar a data (somente ver se tem algo que se parece com "dd/mm/aaaa"), basta verificar isso e se for o caso, remover do valor do CVV.

---

#### Quer mesmo usar regex?

Eu não recomendo, pois como pode ver, há muitas regras diferentes e, embora até seja possível, ela ficaria gigante, difícil de entender e de manter. Já o código acima, na minha opinião é mais simples, não só de fazer, mas também de entender e modificar (para adicionar novas regras/bandeiras/etc, basta ir incrementando os algoritmos, criando novas funções de validação e por aí vai). Fica mais organizado e no fim acaba valendo mais a pena.

Só para você ter uma ideia de como ficaria, segue uma versão "simplificada" com apenas 4 bandeiras:

```
$regex = '#
  (?: (?P<diners>   30[0-5]\d{12,13}   |   3[689]\d{13,14}   )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_diners>\d{4})  )  |
  (?: (?P<amex>  3[47]\d{14}  )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_amex>\d{4})  )  |
  (?: (?P<mastercard>  [25]\d{15}  )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_mastercard>\d{3})  )  |
  (?: (?P<visa>  4\d{15}  )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_visa>\d{3}) )
#x';

$dados = <<<DADOS
30140083|MG 13407061|07309482697|12/01/86|EMILLY L V GOMES|4984012024889591|10/2018|557
3283005|165055881|07309480805|11/18/16|AILTON B TEGON|5549320054855241|6/2018|177
3691100|17714445|07309395883|01/07/67|MARGARETE P SAN|319150122924465|12/2023|8671
DADOS;

$bandeiras = [ 'diners', 'amex', 'mastercard', 'visa'];
if (preg_match_all($regex, $dados, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        foreach ($bandeiras as $b) { // verifica se os named groups foram encontrados
            if ($m[$b]) { // se encontrou, preenche as informações
                $numero_cartao =$m[$b];
                $cvv = $m["cvv_$b"];
                $bandeira = $b;
                break; // se já encontrou uma bandeira, não precisa procurar pelas outras
            }
        }
        echo "cartão $bandeira: $numero_cartao, $cvv\n";
    }
}
```

Eu usei o modificador `x`, que permite escrever a regex em várias linhas e com espaços, para que fique um pouco menos complicado de lê-la (imagine se estivesse tudo em  uma única linha e sem espaços).

Depois eu uso [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou"), para pegar as várias possibilidades.

Por exemplo, para Diners, eu vejo se começa com `30[0-5]` (os dígitos `3` e zero, seguidos de um dígito de zero a `5`), seguido de 12 ou 13 dígitos (`\d{12,13}`), ou se começa com `3[689]`, que pega `36`, `38` ou `39`, seguido de 13 ou 14 dígitos.

Depois pego `\|[^|]+\|`, que é o caractere `|` (escapado com `\` para não ser confundido com a alternância), seguido de um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `|`, seguido de outro `|`, e por fim eu pego o CVV (que neste caso, tem 4 dígitos).

Depois de tudo isso tem uma alternância (o `|` no final da linha) e em seguida tem outra regex para American Express (`3[47]` pega `34` ou `37`, seguido de 14 dígitos - ajuste os valores para o que precisar, eu não sei se pode ter menos, por exemplo), e por aí vai (cada bandeira tem suas regras, incluindo o tamanho do CVV).

Para cada informação eu uso [*named groups*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). Por exemplo, `(?P<visa>  4\d{15}  )` indica que, caso a regex encontre um *match* para `4\d{15}` (o número 4 seguido de 15 dígitos), o resultado estará no grupo chamado "visa". O mesmo vale para o CVV, cada um tem um nome, assim basta verificar se o grupo está preenchido para saber se aquela informação foi encontrada. E como estou usando alternância, então apenas uma das bandeiras será encontrada por vez, por isso eu só preciso procurar pelos grupos até encontrar uma delas.

Mas veja que eu só coloquei quatro bandeiras. Para cada uma delas você teria que adicionar outra regex específica, e será que vale mesmo a pena? Para mim, já está complicado o suficiente, e adicionar mais linhas ali só vai piorar ainda mais. Eu ainda prefiro seguir com a primeira opção (tratar cada linha separadamente, quebrar os dados, criar funções separadas para cada bandeira, etc). Regex é legal, [mas nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Por exemplo, para tratar os casos em que pode ter uma data depois do CVV, bastaria adicionar `(?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?` depois deles (o `?` indica que todo este trecho é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)). Ficaria pior do que já está:

```
$regex = '#
  (?: (?P<diners>   30[0-5]\d{12,13}   |   3[689]\d{13,14}   )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_diners>\d{4})  (?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?  )  |
  (?: (?P<amex>  3[47]\d{14}  )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_amex>\d{4})   (?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?  )  |
  (?: (?P<mastercard>  [25]\d{15}  )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_mastercard>\d{3})  (?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?  )  |
  (?: (?P<visa>  4\d{15}  )  \| [^|]+ \|  (?P<cvv_visa>\d{3})  (?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?  )
#x';
```

Comment: irei tentar e lhe retornarei comentando aqui se deu certo, provável que faça pequenas alterações.. tamo junto guerreiro!!

Comment: @gleisin-dev Atualizei a resposta com a questão da data depois do CVV. De qualquer forma, insisto no que eu disse ao longo de toda a resposta: talvez a primeira solução (`explode` e depois pegar as partes separadamente e criar funções específicas para validar cada parte) seja melhor do que tentar uma única regex que faz tudo

Comment: Show meu amigo!! Valeu mesmo..